# Junit run not picking file src/test/resources. For file required by some dependency jar

Tags: maven-2, resources, junit, testing, surefire

I m facing a issue where test/resource is not picked,but instead jar's main/resource is picked

Scenario is like : Myproject
src/test/resources--- have config.xml w
which should be needed by abc.jar which is a dependecy in Myproject.

When running test case for Myproject its loading config.xml of abc.jar instead of Myproject test/resources. 
- I need to know order in which maven pick resources.
- Or wat im trying is not possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Rephrasing question : Myproject dependency abc.jar class loadFile.java loads config.xml file which under abc src/main/resource. 
When i m running Myproject test case which .xml loadFile.java should pick.
1. abc jar main/resource or
2. Myproject tase/resource

Answer (score 13):

Files from `target/tests-classes` (by default) are included at the **beginning** the test classpath. So when running tests, resources from both `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` are on the classpath but the later has precedence over the former. In other words, if you have a `config.xml` in `src/main/resources` and in `src/test/resouces`:

- `src/main/resources/config.xml` will be packaged in the final artefact **but**
- `src/test/resources/config.xml` will be used when running test

If this is not what you're experiencing, there must be a mistake somewhere else.

If you want to convince yourself you can run `mvn -X test`, this will print the *Test Classpath*. And you'll see that this classpath is made of (in this order):

- `target/test-classes`
- `target/classes`
- the project jar
- the dependencies (including those with a test scope)

Comment: Thanks for reply... its showing as wat u mention. This means config.xml file in test-classes will get preference over config.xml file in some dependencies jar.
But this not happening in my case dependency jar is loading its own .xml rather my test/resources.

Wat i can do to trace it.

Comment: @saddy-dj Who is loading `config.xml` exactly? A test case or a class of a JAR? I think I start to understand what might be the cause of the problem...

Comment: @saddy-dj What code do you use to load the file? Can you update your question with the code snippet?

Comment: Inside abc.jar loadFile.java call fileLoderClass.java getFile()mehtod [fileLoderClass inside someOther.jar]     

fileLoderClass loads file in this way.
inStream =this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(this.configFileName);

config file present in abc.jar

Comment: This is an excellent thing to understand, because for instance log4j.xml could be in the /src/test/properties of the dependent jars but not in /src/main/resources, and when you build using the maven-assembly-plugin it will only pick up the one in the final /src/main/resources and not the others, but their tests can still run (and log).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with my project. So I have TestClassA in ProjectA that calls ClassB from ProjectB. ClassB uses a file in src/test/resources. For some reason this file was not being used. I found out that ProjectA had a file by the same name in its src/test/resources. 
So in summary, even though ClassB was in ProjectB, it was using ProjectA's src/test/resources because that's the project where the test originated.